# Resharper 8.1 and unit Test code

Tags: c#, unit-testing, resharper, assert

Any one knows why resharper 8.1.23.546 when provided the following code, on a  unit test.

```
Assert.IsNotNull(item);
Assert.IsNotNull(item.AddressTypeID);
AddressType item2 = AddressTypeManager.Load(item.AddressTypeID.Value);
```

Resharper gives an invalid Operation warning on line 3. The type of AddressTypeId is int ?
AddressTypeManager.Load is a static method that takes an Int.

```
public static class AddressTypeManager
{
    public static AddressType Load(int addressTypeID)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like a regression bug. ReSharper 8.0.2 did not show a problem on that third line, but 8.1 does. I just upgraded. I would report this to JetBrains. Note that in 8.0.2, if I commented out the second line, the third line got a warning, so it seems 8.0.2 had a working verification of this, and 8.1 does not. To file a bug with Jetbrains, go to http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: If you want to, I can report the bug for you, I've reported bugs there before so I have an account already.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I followed your link and entered a bug on that sit. It just sucks that annoying ugly bug came back.

Comment: One last thing, after some working I found a workaround. replace the Assert.IsNotNull(nullable) for Assert.IsTrue(nullable.HasValue) somehow resharper understood the Assert.IsTrue, but no the Assert.IsNotNull.